# Setting the thumbnailPhoto attribute via PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

At my work we recently upgraded to Lync ( fancy version of office communicator ) and there is a photo field that will display your photo on email and chat.

The problem is, this "default corporate picture" is stored in the active directory object for the user account within the thumbnailPhoto attribute.

Using ADSI I'm allowed to play with setting different values but unfortunately I can't find anything on the net except .NET stuff as far as updating this photo goes.

I've done other stuff in PHP and Active Directory, if anyone has been able to set this photo via PHP I'd love to see how you did it.

THanks in advance!

Comment: If you can do it in .NET, maybe you could [do it in .NET](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/book.dotnet.php)? Also, when you say it is `stored in the active directory object for the user account within the thumbnailPhoto attribute` - do you mean the path to the image is stored there, or the actual image data? Either way, surely it's just a case of updating the value of this attribute, which should be easily accomplished using the LDAP extension, like every other AD-PHP procedure? Or have I missed something obvious?

Comment: I don't have access to .NET but from what I've seen on the net it looks like people are uploading the image data itself to AD.

Comment: Will the LDAP extension let you alter that attribute? If so, it should just be a simple case of reading the data into memory and running a modify query against the directory - obviously the user account used to bind will need permissions in AD to modify the user. If you need to manipulate the image to the correct format, I'm sure [GD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) will be able to do what you need.

Comment: Using the tool that came with it, I found that it uploads the image as an octet string so I suppose if I figure out how to convert an image to an octet string and send that as the updated value to AD I should be good.

Comment: I would say that simply doing `$var = file_get_contents('/path/to/file.jpg');` gives you the image as an "octet string", held in the variable `$var`. It's just the raw binary data of the file. The problem you would be more likely to run into is needing to resample the image to the correct dimensions/encoding and/or format - which is where GD comes in.

Comment: Also, you'll need to take into account the matching rules for whatever attribute is used to store the octet string. The matching rules will determine whether an octet string can be added when the same one (as determined by the matching rules) already exists as a attribute in the entry.

Answer (score 0):

I searched on google for a solution for this problem.
Since I couldn't find anything that fitted my needs i am sharing my solution.

The attribute image is a base64 string that contains the image.

```
if(!isset($_POST["username"]))
    exit(json_encode(array("error" => true, "errormsg" => "No username attr set")));
$username = preg_replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "", $_POST["username"]);

if(!isset($_POST["image"]))
    exit(json_encode(array("error" => true, "errormsg" => "No image attr set")));
$image = base64_decode($_POST["image"]);

// Set LDAP Information
$ds = ldap_connect("ldap://IP_ADDRESS");
$r = ldap_bind($ds, "DOMAIN\USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

// Search for UPN in given OU
$search = "(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName=$username))";
$sr = ldap_search($ds, "OU=OU_NAME,DC=DC_NAME,DC=local", $search);
$data = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);

if($data["count"] == 1){
    // OPTIONAL: Show existing image
    /*echo "<strong>Distinguished Name: </strong>" . $data[0]["dn"] . "<br />";
    if (isset($data[0]["thumbnailphoto"]) && isset($data[0]["thumbnailphoto"][0])) {
        echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($data[0]["thumbnailphoto"][0]) . '" height=200/><br>';
    }
    else {
        echo "<strong>Photo not set</strong><br />";
    }*/

    if(ldap_mod_replace($ds, $data[0]["dn"], array("thumbnailPhoto" => $image))){
        exit(json_encode(array("error" => false, "errormsg" => "thumbnailphoto for user $username was set")));
    }else{
        exit(json_encode(array("error" => true, "errormsg" => "thumbnailphoto for user $username could not be set")));
    }
}elseif($data["count"] == 0){
    exit(json_encode(array("error" => true, "errormsg" => "No user found for $username")));
}elseif($data["count"] > 1){
    exit(json_encode(array("error" => true, "errormsg" => "Multiple users found for $username")));
}
ldap_close($ds);
```